# What is needed to break through the surface of Europa?

Tags: europa

How big does a satelite we send have to be to be able to chrush through the ice layer and dive into the ocean on Europa? If a mission should head there, is this a better way of examining the ocean than landing on the surface and drilling through?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about space exploration and as such it should be asked in space.stackexchange.com

Comment: Eduardo is correct that this is off-topic here, but on-topic on Space Exploration. However, it would be closed as a duplicate of either [What are the constraints for a successful robotic mission to Europa?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/331/what-are-the-constraints-for-a-successful-robotic-mission-to-europa) or [How to explore subsurface oceans (cheaply)?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/756/how-to-explore-subsurface-oceans-cheaply/830#830).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Space Exploration, which is covered on the Space Exploration Stack Exchange site (where answers to this question already exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no feasible way for a human-made probe to crush through Europa's ice layer.

"It is predicted that the outer crust of solid ice is approximately 10–30 km (6–19 mi) thick." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_%28moon%29))

It's not even known, whether there is a liqud ocean at all under Europa's ice layer.

Instead of drilling one could try to slowly melt trough the ice.

Comment: Several tons in an opposing solar orbit would make a pretty impressive bang and vaporize a whole lot of ice which might be sampled by a following probe. But miles of ice would be another thing entirely. Not an ethical way to search for life either.

I like the melt idea better. That would require nuclear power of some kind.